# SQL Server timeouts when starting Visual Studio debugger

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

When I start a database backed ASP.net website using Visual Studio, I often get a SQL Server timeout. When I restart, usually it will respond normally.

I'm able to interact with SQL Server normally using Management Studio.

How can I diagnose this issue?

Comment: If you just run it using "start without debugging", do you get any error messages? Could you share a screen shot about the detailed error messages? I know that certain configuration would be related to the timeout like in web.config or connection string: http://geekswithblogs.net/chrishan/archive/2007/07/18/114030.aspx or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230244/sql-connection-timeout, but more or less, you also would think about your code itself.

Comment: Try to use Sql Server Profiler

Comment: @Ian Warburton, What about this issue now? Would you please share us the latest information about it?

Comment: I'm going to try a reinstall of SQL Server.

Comment: Does it work well now after you re-install the SQL Server?

Comment: Start without debugging has the same issues

Comment: I think I was out of memory.